# Two weeks pass, and I freeze

Tags: riddle, word

> Two weeks pass, and I freeze,
> But not to cold temperature,
> Stars are all around me,
> My owners clean me up,
> People often pass by me.

What am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be looking for

> Stack Exchange [chat rooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/).

Two weeks past, and I freeze, But not to cold temperature,

> Jeff Atwood [says](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/662) chat rooms worth retaining which are inactive for 14 days will be frozen.

Stars are all around me,

> Users star notable messages.

My owners clean me up

> Owners can move messages to other rooms or trash.

People often pass by me

> Users go to them for discussion.

Comment: Correct! Congrats!

Answer (score 2):

> Milk

Here's why I think it is that answer above.

Hint 1:

> "Two weeks past and I freeze, but not to cold temperature." Milk goes bad after a few weeks, and it becomes curdles and solid and all that. Though it is clearly not because of cold temperature.

Hint 2:

> "Stars are all around me" Milky way.

Hint 3:

> "My owners clean me up." In the milking process, the milk is really sanitized to make sure that the quality is just right and to avoid contamination and all.

Hint 4:

> "People often pass by me." Milk is, almost everywhere. Really ubiquitous sight in supermarkets, etc.

Comment: Nice answer! Not intended though.